# knockoutJs / Bootstrap with code pretty printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, pretty-print

On this page I'm already using KnockoutJs and Bootstrap.

I have a page where I must show code (for now just JSON) pretty printed. The div content is an observable on KnockoutJs, the content will change with the time.

The question is:
How do I have the content of the div always coloured (it may take a short time to pretty print)?

Thanks all

Comment: can you either show code or make a jsfiddle of what you have done so far

Comment: Do you have a JSON formatter that you'd like to use with knockout?

Comment: It looks like PrettyPrint is a [client-side](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prettyprint/nipdlgebaanapcphbcidpmmmkcecpkhg?hl=en) Chrome app, so I'd look into [Google-Code-Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) instead.